# Install custom hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, languages, tlmgr

I am trying to install custom hyphenation file.

### Background info

Friend of mine already made a hyphenation file for my language and sent it to tug. Will it pass codereview sooner and when it will be deployed is unknown. So trying to install it manually to do my job.

### What I did

#### Try 1

I put the `loadhyph-xx.tex`, `hypg-xx.tex` and other files under  `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8` directory in Ubuntu/Debian. Then modified `language.dat`, `language.dat.lua`, `language.def` manually. When I compile hyphenation is not loaded. The way I check is tex file where hyphenation is defined has `\message`. And in fact hyphenation does not work.

#### Try 2

Content of `language.dat` says that I should not modify it manually instead I need to do local changes and use `tlmgr` to generate config.

I followed the instruction. When I run `tlmgr generate` it says:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: action `generate' not supported in usermode!
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Tried with/without sudo, init user tree, sudo bash etc. It is the same.

### Question

What is the proper way of installing hyphenation configs.

Thanks.

Comment: As the documentation says (https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#generate) local additions should go into language-local.dat, language-local.def, or language-local.dat.lua. You also shouldn't install local files into texmf-dist, use e.g. texmf-local or your texmfhome. After you recreated the system files with `generate language` you should then recreate also the formats with fmtutil-sys.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer. In that case do you know how to deal with `action 'generate' not supported in usermode` issue? What is usermode and how I bypass it?

Comment: I'm on windows. But the "running on Debian, switching to user mode!" probably means that you don't use a vanilla texlive but something provided by debian and that they force user mode (you can force it manually with `--user-mode`), so you probably will have to ask some debian people. You could try on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: You don't identify your language, but if it's one that's not yet supported by `babel` or `polyglossia`, you might consider approaching the developers of those packages about adding it.  They're receptive to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From The TeXbook, p. 449

> The exception dictionary is dynamic, but the pattern dictionary is static: To change
> TEX’s current set of hyphenation patterns, you must give an entirely new set, and
> TEX will spend a little time putting them into a form that makes the hyphenation algo-
> rithm efficient. The command format is \patterns{〈patterns〉}, where 〈patterns〉 is a se-
> quence of 〈pattern〉 items separated by spaces. This command is available only in INITEX, not
> in production versions of TEX, since the process of pattern compression requires extra mem-
> ory that can be put to better use in a production system. INITEX massages the patterns and out-
> puts a format file that production versions can load at high speed.

Comment: I already have the file where patterns are defined (`\patterns{......`). My question is how to install it?

Comment: @AdilAliyev You can only do it by making a format with INITEX.

Comment: Any documentation for that? Thanks

Comment: @AdilAliyev https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/cfgguide.pdf should be a good starting point.